# How to set DateTimeInput timezone in React-Admin

Tags: reactjs, timezone, react-admin

My API returns datetime in format **'2021-12-31T16:00:00.000Z'**

And I would like to use DateTimeInput and always display in **UTC+8 timezone**.
When user saves the form, it should convert back to this format **'2021-12-31T16:00:00.000Z'**.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this behaviour?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try setting the timezone in the `options` prop like this:

https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/5116#issuecomment-834683492

You can also use the `parse` and `format` functions as explained here:

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#transforming-input-value-tofrom-record

Comment: Seems only DateField has `options` prop, but not for DateTimeInput